# Search functionality without mutating the Original array when template is binded with Original array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, find

In my template I have bound this `snapShotArray`. And the `snapShotArray` variable is being filled with data by a REST endpoint call.

```
<div class="col col-md-4 filter-by-cam">
      <input type="text" name="search" value="search" [(ngModel)]="search" #searchSnaps="ngModel"
        (keyup)="searchSnapshot(search)" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!search"
          (click)="searchSnapshot(searchSnaps.value)">Search
        </button>

    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!noData" class="game-board col-md-12">
        <div class="box camera-view-container col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of snapShotArray; let i = index; ">
          <img class="box-img camera-view" id="img{{i}}" src="{{item.image}}" crossOrigin="Anonymous">
          <div class="cam-feed">
            <span> {{item.name}}</span>
            <p>Last captured: {{item.lastCapturedDate}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Component.ts :**

```
public searchSnapshot(name: string) {
 let b = a.filter(item => item.name === name);
}
```

**Question:**

What I want is to search the `snapShotArray` array and return a specific object which matches text entered by user. And once the user clears the textbox, replace the `snapShotArray` by all previous objects or previously fetch data?

I know that `Filter` will not mutate the origianal array. But where I'm stuck now is filtering and replacing the original `snapShotArray` when having it bound with the template.  Basically a filter functionality on the client side. How do I achieve this?

Comment: While you see many tutorials and examples showing sorting and filtering using pipes, it’s not recommend to do that for performance reasons https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe . Doing filtering in the component is not only perfectly fine either though RxJS operators or array prototype functions, it’s the recommended approach. Examples like flying heroes pipe is fine for small data sets, but you can absolutely have performance depredations as your app grows with those kinds of filter pipes.

Comment: I've upvoted it. That being said, keep in mind you can always keep `snapShotArray` unchanged and create an additional variable `filteredSnapShotArray` that is based on `snapShotArray`. While it's not exactly the same as your issue, here is that possible approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740256/how-can-i-implement-a-category-filter-in-angular2/58740972#58740972.

Comment: Thanks alot mate i'll take look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a filter, use a pipe on the clientside. Check 
https://angular.io/guide/pipes

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of (heroes | flyingHeroes)">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

And here is how to make one

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { Flyer } from './heroes';

@Pipe({ name: 'flyingHeroes' })
export class FlyingHeroesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allHeroes: Flyer[]) {
    return allHeroes.filter(hero => hero.canFly);
  }
}
```

For your specific case:

```
<div class="box camera-view-container col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of (snapShotArray | searchFilter: searchValue); let i = index; ">
```

And then set the search value in your component. Your filter should be pretty straightforward, as it will just return the filtered array, without saving it anywhere.

Comment: What sort of performance implact this proposed solution will take. I'm playing with `base64` Image dataset.

Comment: No more than the usual. The change detection will only start when either the search parameter will change or the snapshot array.

Answer (score 1):

always use pipe to filtering

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'snapshotFilter' })
export class SnapshotFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(snapshotArr: [] , searchValue : string) {
        return snapshotArr.filter(snapshot=> {
            snapshot.name === searchValue
        });
    }
}
```

here your HTML

```
<div class="col col-md-4 filter-by-cam">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="search" [(ngModel)]="search" #searchSnaps="ngModel"
        (keyup)="searchSnapshot(search)" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!search" (click)="searchSnapshot(searchSnaps.value)">Search
    </button>

</div>

<div *ngIf="!noData" class="game-board col-md-12">
    <div class="box camera-view-container col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of snapShotArray | snapshotFilter : searchValue ; let i = index; ">
        <img class="box-img camera-view" id="img{{i}}" src="{{item.image}}" crossOrigin="Anonymous">
        <div class="cam-feed">
            <span> {{item.name}}</span>
            <p>Last captured: {{item.lastCapturedDate}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your component

```
public searchSnapshot(search: string) {
     this.searchValue = search;
}
```

don't forget to include pipe in your app module

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the solution.. I'm more concerned about the performance aspect it too. How much of performance impact that this would give. Im using `base64` Image dataset. Highly appreciate a upvote on this. Badly want professionals to take a look at it.

Comment: as a performance i think pipe it the best solution for filtering it's native Js code you can check these  [https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes]
[https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/11/12/faster-angular-applications-pure-pipes-memoization-pure-functions-part-2/][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289826/angular-performance-pipe-vs-getter]

Comment: This isnt working once I enter a value entire generated array vanishes from displaying